# Determine SSL/TLS version using Wireshark

Tags: encryption, tls, wireshark, sql-server

Using Wireshark, I am trying to determine the version of SSL/TLS that is being used with the encryption of data between a client workstation and another workstation on the same LAN running SQL Server. Documentation on this subject suggests to look at the ServerHello and ClientHello messages but I cannot see any such messages in the Wireshark message feed. I am using this display filter:

tcp.len>1 && tcp.port==1433

I can confirm that encryption of data is occurring and that the packets displayed using the above filter are related to the SQL Server data transfer that I am wanting to examine. This is what the Wireshark message feed looks like:

[image]

EDIT:

Here is the packet details pane of the 4th packet after invoking a database connection and selecting Follow-->TCP Stream:

[image: Packet Details Pane]

This is what I see when analyzing using Microsoft Message Analyzer. The TLS details pane is for the Client Hello packet.

[image: Microsoft Message Analyzer Main Pane]

[image: Microsoft Message Analyzer TLS Details Pane]

Comment: It should be in the Hellos. Can you confirm that you have the initial handshake packets?

Comment: What I have posted in the image above is all I can see.

Comment: Is there something else I need to include in the display filter?

Comment: You have to check in the packet details pane https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUsePacketDetailsPaneSection.html

Comment: I have looked extensively through the packet details panes and can't see anything that looks like an SSL or TLS version number

Comment: If I remove the filters, I can see messages with protocol TLSv1.2 which have a "Secure Sockets Layer" node in the packet details pane which clearly shows the TLS version.

Comment: But there is nothing like that in any of the packets that are related to SQL Server traffic.

Comment: Can you filter for all packets that comprise the TLS handshake ssl.handshake

Comment: Yes I can. Can I expect the handshakes related to the SQL Server connections to be excluded with the filter "tcp.len>1 && tcp.port==1433"? If so, how can I know which of the handshakes are related to SQL Server?

Comment: Well, you should know at least it's IP address ;)

Comment: I tried that. Filter "ssl.handshake && ip.addr==192.168.15.10 && ip.addr==192.168.15.6" returned no messages.

Comment: The server is 10 and the client is 6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48710/discussion-between-adam86-and-guru-josh).

Comment: If possible please share the pcap. You can't find the ssl handshake in Wireshark using the ssl filter as the TDS protocol uses SSL/TLS internally using SChannel(Windows internal implementation of SSL/TLS). You need to go through the structure of TDS protocol mentioned in TDS protocol documentation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Adding a new answer which should be definitive, leaving the old around as it's useful debug for how we got here.  Credit for pointing to the actual answer in comments goes to @P4cK3tHuNt3R and @dave_thompson_085)

> Using Wireshark, I am trying to determine the version of SSL/TLS that
>   is being used with the encryption of data between a client workstation
>   and another workstation on the same LAN running SQL Server.

You are viewing a connection which uses [MS-TDS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx) ("Tabular Data Stream Protocol"):

```
...the Tabular Data Stream Protocol, which facilitates interaction with
a database server and provides for authentication and channel encryption
negotiation; specification of requests in SQL (including Bulk Insert);
invocation of a stored procedure, also known as a Remote Procedure Call
(RPC); returning of data; and Transaction Manager Requests. It is an 
application layer request/response protocol.
```

If you view the [TDS protocol documentatio](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-TDS/[MS-TDS].pdf)n, it specifies that the SSL packets are encapsulated within a TDS wrapper:

```
A TLS/SSL negotiation packet is a PRELOGIN (0x12) packet header encapsulated
with TLS/SSL payload.
```

In the Microsoft Message Analyzer screencap you posted, we can see the TDS header (boxed in Red, starts with 0x12), followed several bytes later by the TLS CLIENT_HELLO packet (boxed in Blue, starts with 0x16 0x03 0x03):

[image: TDS and encapsulated TLS headers]

- `0x16` is the TLS "Handshake" header indicator,
- `0x03 0x03` is the TLS version (TLS 1.2, as per [RFC 5246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt)):

  The version of the protocol being employed.  This document
  describes TLS Version 1.2, which uses the version { 3, 3 }.  The
  version value 3.3 is historical, deriving from the use of {3, 1}
  for TLS 1.0.

**So the simple answer to your question, "determine the version of SSL/TLS", is "TLS 1.2".**

Now, I've seen varying reports as to whether Wireshark can properly parse TDS packets with encoded TLS.  I think that the answer is what you started with - it will tell you TLS is there, but won't parse the details as it would with a native TLS session.

As per [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023589/how-can-i-decode-sql-server-traffic-with-wireshark), it appears that Microsoft Network Monitor is capable of parsing both levels of encapsulation.  And a comment therein states that [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) is the newer equivalent of that tool.

Answer (score 9):

I just use this filter in Wireshark to find TLS 1.0 traffic:

```
ssl.handshake.version==0x0301
```

`0x0302` is TLS 1.1 and `0x0303` is TLS 1.2.

Comment: How did you figure out that TLS 1.1 is 0x0302 and TLS 1.2 is 0x0303? Is it documented somewhere or did you check for both and observed it.

Comment: This is indicated as deprecated by my version of Wireshark, is there an up to date alternative?

Answer (score 6):

**(Ignore this answer, which I'm leaving for historical data, and read my other answer, which explains what's actually going on)**

Update after an example packet was added to the question -

The packet you've provided is clearly not a TLS packet.  Looking at the hex you've provided, the first three octets of the TCP data are `12 01 00`, but for a TLS packet the first three bytes should be `16 03 0X`, where 0x16 means TLS "Handshake" record type, 0x03 means SSLv3/TLSv1.*, and the 0x0X indicates the TLS version - 0x01 for TLS 1.0, 0x02 for TLS 1.1, and 0x03 for TLS 1.2.

Additionally, there's a cleartext "sqlexpress2012" string in the packet, which wouldn't be there if this was a TLS Client Hello.

[image: Marked up copy of provided packet]

(How did I decide `12 01 00` was the beginning of the data?  The first 14 bytes of the packet are the Ethernet header.  The next 20 bytes are the IP header.  The 13th byte of the TCP header is 0x50, and the first nibble of that byte times 4 is the TCP header length, so 5*4 = 20.  So the first bytes of actual data start 54 bytes in at `12 01 00 6c 00 00 ...`)

So if Wireshark won't display this as TLS, that's because it isn't.  You should revisit your server configuration.

---

**Original answer:**

Because those packets are not on a standard TLS port (e.g., 443) you need to tell Wireshark to interpret them as TLS packets.  By default port 1433 is not interpreted as having TLS; the default for TDS is to be unencrypted.  So by itself Wireshark will not parse it as TLS:

[image: Wireshark default decoding for port 1433]

In order to change this, right-click on one of the packets and select "Decode As".  Make sure the port "value" is set to 1433 and then set "Current" to SSL:

[image: Wireshark "Decode As" dialog]

Click OK and when you return to the packets you'll see they're now interpreted in more detail:

[image: Packets with SSL decoding turned on]

Finally, if you look at the detail pane for one of the packets (I suggest using the server hello, not the client hello, in case protocol was adjusted) you'll see the TLS version quite clearly:

[image: Packet detail showing TLS version]

Comment: After doing that, I am not seeing that level of detail and I am not seeing a Client Hello or Server Hello packet. However, the Protocol column now displays "TLSv1.2" for every packet. On connecting to the server, I am getting a series of packets with Info "Ignored Unknown Record". When I bring up the details pane for those packets, the "Secure Sockets Layer" node does not display the TLS version details as per your screen shot. I take it though that the Protocols column is giving me the correct information that I require?

Comment: @GuruJosh at this point I'm wondering if your traffic is really TLS like you think it is.  Can you filter onto a single connection (tcp.stream eq 0, for example), double click on the 4th packet (first data packet after TCP 3-way handshake), and update your question with a screenshot of the bottom pane ("packet bytes")?

Comment: Exactly which display filter should I apply? If I apply the filter "tcp.len>1 && tcp.port==1433 && tcp.stream eq 0", this doesn't show any packets even when I invoke a database connection between server and client. If I apply the filter "tcp.stream eq 0" then the message feed gets contaminated with an ongoing stream of other packets and I can't distinguish which ones are invoked by a database connection.

Comment: If it provides any kind of clue as to what is happening, if I disable TLS 1.2 then where the Protocols column was displaying "TLSv1.2", it is now displaying "TLSv1.1". Also I can confirm that the traffic is encrypted because when I remove "Encrypt=True" from the connection string, I can see plain text SQL on the right-hand-side of the packet bytes pane.

Comment: And if I examine the packets using Microsoft Message Analyzer instead (with display filter "tcp.Port==1433") , I can see the Client Hello and Server Hello messages. If I examine these packets, I can see "TLS 1.2" displayed in the Value column where the Type column = "TLS.ProtocolVersion". I can't see the same information displayed in Wireshark.

Comment: @GuruJosh with "tcp.len>1 && tcp.port==1433" as your filter, pick one of the packets you think is from a connection you care about, then right click and click on "Follow > TCP Stream".  This will automatically apply a filter of "tcp.stream eq X" where X is whatever stream in the file you happened to be looking at.  Then the hexdump of the 4th packet will show us what the putative Client Hello looks like.

Comment: I have followed this process and posted the image.

Comment: @GuruJosh I've updated the answer based on the packet hex image you posted - in short, this isn't SSL/TLS, so Wireshark will have problems interpreting it as such.

Comment: I'm stumped as to why this is happening. All of the required client and server software is installed. When I remove "Encrypt=True" from the connection string, plain text SQL starts appearing in the packet details pane so some kind of encryption is happening. Moreover, when I analyze the packets using Microsoft Message Analyzer, I am seeing the packets and TLS hex values that you describe. I have posted screenshots of the packet feed and Client Hello packet details to illustrate. Could this be something to do with the way Wireshark is configured?

Comment: As a leeter correctly commented on the Q, SqlServer wraps TLS _inside_ TDS, which is the protocol SqlServer (and Sybase before it) uses for everything, so you won't ever find the TLS header at the beginning of the TCP body. There was a Q on this recently (but I can't find it) where someone told me **Wireshark v2** can decode this; the last time I had occasion to try was before v2 came out, around v1.6 or so, and that did not.

Comment: I am using the latest Wireshark v2.22. Is the decoding you mention what was outlined by @gowenfawr? i.e. Decode as SSL etc? Are you saying that it's possible that TLS encryption may be happening but some kind of further decoding is required?