# How to tell if FTP connection is secured with TLS1.2

Tags: tls, ftp

I need to be sure that the FTP requests that my Windows 10 app is making are secured with TLS1.2 because our ftp host is going to start charging more money if we use any other version.

I've tried looking at the packets with both Wire Shark and Microsoft Network Monitor, but all I can see is

```
ReplyMessage:  Command AUTH okay; starting TLS connection.
```

The protocol is FTP and the port is 21.

Is there something else in a packet that will give away the TLS version?

Is there a way I can definitively tell that we're using TLS1.2?

Comment: In Wireshark you can see the TLS handshake after the AUTH reply and in there you can also see the TLS version used as described in the various other questions.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich The [linked question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142939/determine-ssl-tls-version-using-wireshark)s solved my issue.